# Detecting the parameter types in a Spirit semantic action

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, boost-spirit

General case: I can't figure out why my Spirit grammar/semantics actions aren't compiling.

Sometimes, the compiler will complain about assignment or type incompatibilities and I have no clue what's wrong. The problem occurs in two main areas:

- predicting the type of synthesized attributes for a rule/expression

  - consequently, predicting what types of attributes can be legally defined as the exposed attribute for the rule (relying in builting conversions, fusion adaptors or Spirit customization points)
- matching the argument types for my semantic action so that

  - the compiler will be able to compile the function invocation
  - the invocation will not invoke unnecessary implicit conversions in the process

The compiler error is not exactly tractable, and either the documentation is wrong, or I misunderstood it.

**Is there a way to find out *exactly* what Spirit passes into my semantic action, anyway?**

#### Example code:

```
struct mybase             { int a,b; };
struct myderived : mybase { int c,d; };

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(mybase,    (int,a)(int,b));
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(myderived, (int,a)(int,b)(int,c)(int,d));

auto base_expr = int_ >> int_; // avoids assigning to struct attribute

rule<decltype(f), mybase()   , space_type> base_       = int_ >> int_;
rule<decltype(f), myderived(), space_type> derived_    = base_ >> int_ >> int_;

myderived data;
bool ok = phrase_parse(f,l,derived_,space,data);
```

This code won't compile, with a huge amount of impenetrable errors.

(*loosely adapted from a posting on the [spirit-general](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/struct-derived-struct-fusion-adapted-and-the-sequence-operator-tc4259090.html) list*)

Comment: +1 <starred> exactly what I'm struggling with on a daily basis, as a beginning user...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For clarity - the error here is that `base_ >> int_ >> int_` was used as the expression for a rule that creates a `myderived`, and since `base_` is fixed to type `mybase`, we'd have to create a `myderrived` from a `mybase` and two `int`s, but there's nothing to tell Spirit how to do that.

You can get boost to print out the type of the value that boost creates from parsing `base_ >> int_ >> int_` by defining a functor that will take any parameters, and tell you what they are (the following code is adapted from some code sehe put on SO chat):

```
struct what_is_the_attr
{
    template <typename> struct result { typedef bool type; };

    template <typename T>
    static void print_the_type()
    {
        std::cout << "    ";
        std::cout << typeid(T).name();
        if(std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value)
            std::cout << " const";
        if(std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value)
            std::cout << " &&";
        else if(std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value)
            std::cout << " &";
    }

    template <typename Th, typename Th2, typename... Tt>
    static void print_the_type()
    {
        print_the_type<Th>();
        std::cout << ",\n";
        print_the_type<Th2, Tt...>();
    }

    template <typename... Ts>
    void operator()(Ts&&...) const
    {
        std::cout << "what_is_the_attr(\n";
        print_the_type<Ts...>();
        std::cout << ")" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Then to use it, use the above actor in a semantic action on initializer for your faulty rule:

```
std::string input = "1 2 3 4";
auto f(std::begin(input)), l(std::end(input));

rule<decltype(f), mybase()   , space_type> base_    = int_ >> int_;
rule<decltype(f), myderived(), space_type> derived_ = (base_ >> int_ >> int_)[what_is_the_attr()];

myderived data;
bool ok = phrase_parse(f,l,derived_,space,data);
```

*Note, you cannot use automatic attribute propagation with `%=` (unless you remove the exposed attribute type from the rule's declared type).*

Running this should then yield an encoded type, which can be decoded with `c++filt -t`: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f5c90240b96d037)**

```
$ g++ 9404189.cpp -std=c++0x
$ ./a.out |c++filt -t
what_is_the_attr(
    boost::fusion::vector3<mybase, int, int> &,
    boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::unused_type&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> > &,
    bool &)
```

The first line, `boost::fusion::vector3<mybase, int, int>`, least tells you that boost is trying to create your return type from 3 objects of types `mybase`, `int` and `int`.

Comment: +1 for the type trait wizardry for improved typename printing. Cool!

Answer (score 10):

I could solve the problem for this particular case (in fact [we discussed options on the list](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/struct-derived-struct-fusion-adapted-and-the-sequence-operator-tc4259090.html)), but really, this kind of
'enigmatic' error creeps up more often with Boost Spirit and it would be nice
to get a handle on the general class of problems.

Your first resource should be the *excellent* spirit documentation, which
details exactly what the synthesized attribute will be for a given parser
primitive, operator or directive. See [the Reference
section](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference.html)
to [Spirit Qi Docs](http://boost-spirit.com/home/doc/).

In some cases, I have taken to shifting the focus from 'trying to pry the
information from the compiler error list' to 'actively querying Spirit for the
types it passes'. The technique I use for this is the Polymorphic Callable Type
(see Spirit/Fusion docs).

Here is one that uses GCC specific APIs to *pretty [sic] print* the types it detects:

### Functor `what_is_the_attr`

```
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> std::string nameofType(const T& v) {
    int     status;
    char   *realname = abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(v).name(), 0, 0, &status);
    std::string name(realname? realname : "????");
    free(realname);
    return name;
}

struct what_is_the_attr {
    template <typename> struct result { typedef bool type; };

    template <typename T> bool operator()(T& attr) const {
        std::cerr << "what_is_the_attr: " << nameofType(attr) << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};
```

### Sample use: detect synthesized attribute type

You can use it to detect exactly what type the synthesized attribute type of a
parser expression actually ends up being:

```
template <typename Exp>
    void detect_attr_type(const Exp& exp)
{
    using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

    const char input[] = "1 2 3 4";
    auto f(std::begin(input)), l(std::end(input)-1);

    bool dummy = phrase_parse(
            f, l, 
            exp [ what_is_the_attr() ],
            space);
}
```

> (**Note:** *this shows a limitation of the approach - the technique assumes you
>   have an 'otherwise' working grammar and you know how to pass an input that
>   satisfies the expression enough to trigger the semantic action. In most cases,
>   this will be true when you are hacking on your Spirit parser, though*)

Let's test it. E.g. let's see what the difference is between and expression of
medium complexity, and the same wrapped inside a `qi::raw[]` directive:

```
int main()
{
    detect_attr_type(       -(int_ >> *int_)    );
    detect_attr_type( raw [ -(int_ >> *int_) ] );
}
```

Output:

```
what_is_the_attr: boost::optional<boost::fusion::vector2<int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >
what_is_the_attr: boost::iterator_range<char const*>
```

At the bottom, we will apply this to the question in the OP.

### Sample use: detecting types passed into Semantic Actions

We could use the same unary function object (`what_is_the_attr`) to detect
these, however, semantic actions can take any number of arguments, so we need
to generalize. This would be tedious work, if it weren't for ***variadic
template*** (woot! for c++0x):

```
struct what_are_the_arguments {
    template <typename...> struct result { typedef bool type; };

    template <typename... T> bool operator()(const T&... attr) const {
        std::vector<std::string> names { nameofType(attr)... };
        std::cerr << "what_are_the_arguments:\n\t";
        std::copy(names.begin(), names.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cerr, "\n\t"));
        std::cerr << '\n';
        return true;
    }
};
```

Repeated for the above test cases reveals that Spirit actually tries to call
the semantic action with *three arguments* if possible (as [documented](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/action.html#spirit.qi.reference.action.expression_semantics)):

```
what_are_the_arguments:
    boost::optional<boost::fusion::vector2<int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >
    boost::spirit::unused_type
    bool

what_are_the_arguments:
    boost::iterator_range<char const*>
    boost::spirit::unused_type
    bool
```

But the nice thing is, that you can now apply this to any semantic action:

```
template <typename ExpWSA> void test(const ExpWSA& exp)
{
    const char input[] = "1 2 3 4";
    auto f(std::begin(input)), l(std::end(input)-1);

    qi::phrase_parse(f, l, exp, qi::space);
}

int main()
{
    test(-(-double_ >> *int_) [ phx::bind(what_are_the_arguments(), _1, _2, _0, phx::ref(std::cout), 42) ]);
}
```

Printing, for this (sorry) very contrived example:

```
what_are_the_arguments:
    boost::optional<double>
    std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >
    boost::fusion::vector2<boost::optional<double>, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >
    std::ostream
    int
```

### Applied to the OP

The synthesized attribute of the `derived` rule is *not* the same as for `int_>>int_>>int_>>int_`:

```
auto base_expr = int_ >> int_; // avoids assigning to struct attribute

rule<const char*, mybase(), space_type> base_       = base_expr;

test(base_     >> int_ >> int_ [ what_is_the_attr() ] );
test(base_expr >> int_ >> int_ [ what_is_the_attr() ] );
```

Will print

```
what_is_the_attr: boost::fusion::vector3<mybase, int, int>
what_is_the_attr: boost::fusion::vector4<int, int, int, int>
```

There is your problem. We discussed some workarounds based on this diagnostic in the [original thread](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/struct-derived-struct-fusion-adapted-and-the-sequence-operator-tc4259090.html) (and see the other answers here). But this post should help answering the general case question.

## Full code listing

In integrated form, compiled with gcc 4.6.1 --std=c++0x and boost 1_48:

```
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename T> std::string nameofType(const T& v)
{
    int     status;
    char   *realname = abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(v).name(), 0, 0, &status);
    std::string name(realname? realname : "????");
    free(realname);

    return name;
}

struct what_is_the_attr {
    template <typename> struct result { typedef bool type; };

    template <typename T> bool operator()(T& attr) const {
        std::cerr << "what_is_the_attr: " << nameofType(attr) << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};

struct what_are_the_arguments {
    template <typename...> struct result { typedef bool type; };

    template <typename... T> bool operator()(const T&... attr) const {
        std::vector<std::string> names { nameofType(attr)... };
        std::cerr << "what_are_the_arguments:\n\t";
        std::copy(names.begin(), names.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cerr, "\n\t"));
        std::cerr << '\n';
        return true;
    }
};

#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

struct mybase             { int a,b; };
struct myderived : mybase { int c,d; };

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(mybase,    (int,a)(int,b));
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(myderived, (int,a)(int,b)(int,c)(int,d));

template <typename ExpWSA>
void test(const ExpWSA& exp)
{
    using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

    const char input[] = "1 2 3 4";
    auto f(std::begin(input)), l(std::end(input)-1);

    bool dummy = phrase_parse(f, l, exp, space);
}

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

    // Diagnostics for the OP case
    auto base_expr = int_ >> int_;                                   // avoids assigning to struct attribute
    rule<const char*, mybase(), space_type> base_       = base_expr;

    // Derived rule, different formulations
    test((base_     >> int_ >> int_) [ what_is_the_attr() ] );
    test((base_expr >> int_ >> int_) [ what_is_the_attr() ] );

    // Applied to attribute types
    test(raw [ -(int_ >> *int_) ]  [ what_is_the_attr() ] );
    test(-(int_ >> *int_)          [ what_is_the_attr() ] );

    // applied to semantic actions - contrived example
    namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
    test(-(-double_ >> *int_) [ phx::bind(what_are_the_arguments(), _1, _2, _0, phx::ref(std::cout), 42) ]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fortunately for MSVC 2019 demangling is not necessary!

Comment: @ClaudiuCruceanu even more fortunately you can use Boost to portably demangle these days: https://godbolt.org/z/Kb11GfqGn, or even more modern with libfmt/std::format: https://godbolt.org/z/3qa8EebdW

Comment: Ups! I lost 2 days searching for __cxa_demangle replacement (e.g. UnDecorateSymbolName), testing also je4d variant and founding that external "c++filt - t" and of course __cxa_demangle are not needed in MSVS compilers.

Comment: Why in the boost demangle case at godbold it cannot compile "test( (-(-double_ >> *int_)) [ phx::bind( what_are_the_arguments(), _1, _2, _0, phx::ref( std::cout), 42)]);". Explanation: in your last case "-(rule)[sem_ac]" the -  has lower priority than [] so it is not catched by semantic action, so I tried to catch it with "(-(rule))[sem_act]". P.S. the same in MSVS

Comment: @ClaudiuCruceanu yeah, the language rules apply; _1 and _2 do not have meaning there, so this works: https://godbolt.org/z/7arq335hP

Comment: Info for anybody interested in compiling with MSVS: from the above examples only [godbolt.org/z/Kb11GfqGn](https://godbolt.org/z/Kb11GfqGn) works for MSVC 2019 as <fmt/ranges.h>is not available. Compiler explorer lists MSVS compilers but are gives an error when trying to use.