# Compound Attribute generation in Boost::Spirit parse rule

Tags: boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have the following parsing rule:

```
filter = (input >> (qi::repeat(0,2)[char_(';') >> input]))
```

`input` is a rule that returns a `std::vector<int>`, vector that I will just call `vec` for short.

The question is: What compound attribute would the `filter` rule return?

I tried:

```
fusion::vector <vec,std::vector <fusion::vector <char,vec> > >
```

But it fails and I don't know why.

Comment: Oh. Lol I somehow read `vec of short` instead of _for short_. Oh well, `s/short/int/` in my answer wlll do

Comment: See also [Detecting the parameter types in a Spirit semantic action](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9404955/85371)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The attribute types resulting of the parser expressions are [quite](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/repeat.html#spirit.qi.reference.directive.repeat.attributes) well-[documented](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/sequence.html#spirit.qi.reference.operator.sequence.attributes). But that can be disorienting and timeconsuming.

Here's a trick: send in a sentinel to detect the attribute type:

```
struct Sniffer
{
    typedef void result_type;

    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T const&) const { std::cout << typeid(T).name() << "\n"; }
};
```

then using the folliing parser expression

```
 (input >> (qi::repeat(0,2)[qi::char_(';') >> input])) [ Sniffer() ]
```

will dump:

```
N5boost6fusion7vector2ISt6vectorIsSaIsEES2_INS1_IcS4_EESaIS5_EEEE
```

which `c++filt -1` will tell you represents:

```
boost::fusion::vector2<
    std::vector<short, std::allocator<short> >, 
    std::vector<boost::fusion::vector2<char, std::vector<short, std::allocator<short> > >, 
                std::allocator<boost::fusion::vector2<char, std::vector<short, std::allocator<short> > > 
            > > 
 >
```

See it live on Coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3e767990571f8d0917aae745bccfa520-5c1d29aa57205c65cfb2587775d52d22

```
boost::fusion::vector2<std::vector<short, std::allocator<short> >, std::vector<std::vector<short, std::allocator<short> >, std::allocator<std::vector<short, std::allocator<short> > > > >
```

It might be so surprisingly complicated, in part, because `char_(";")` could have been `';'` (or more explicitely `lit(';')`). [Constrast with this (Coliru)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d082c65751264fb206b8ede55c47c96d-5c1d29aa57205c65cfb2587775d52d22):

```
boost::fusion::vector2<
    std::vector<short, ... >, 
    std::vector<std::vector<short, std::allocator<short> >, ... > >
```

This should answer your question.

### Sidenotes: *parsing* things

Don't underestimate automatic attribute propagation in Spirit. Frequently, you don't have to bother with the *exact* exposed types of attributes. Instead, rely on the (many) attribute transformations that Spirit uses to assign them to your supplied attribute references.

I trust you know the list-operator (`%`) in spirit? I'll show you how you can use it without further ado:

```
vector<vector<short>> data;

qi::parse(f, l, qi::short_ % ',' % ';', data);
```

Now, if you need to enforce the fact that it may be 1-3 elements, you might employ an `eps` with a Phoenix action to assert the maximum size:

```
const string x = "1,2,3;2,3,4;3,4,5";
auto f(begin(x)), l(end(x));

if (qi::parse(f, l, 
        (qi::eps(phx::size(qi::_val) < 2) > (qi::short_ % ',')) % ';'
        , data))
{
    cout << karma::format(karma::short_ % ',' % ';', data) << "\n";
}
cout << "remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
```

Prints:

```
1,2,3;2,3,4
remaining unparsed: ';3,4,5'
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the detailed and informative answer!
The strange thing is that the attribute that your code suggests is the same as the one I tried! The only difference is that you are explicitly specifying a `fusion::vector2` and I was just naming it a `fusion::vector` that takes 2 template arguments. To my understanding, both should be equivalent. To sum it up, this works: `fusion::vector <vec,std::vector <fusion::vector2 <char,vec> > >`
while this doesn't:
`fusion::vector <vec,std::vector <fusion::vector <char,vec> > >`
I don't know if it's a bug or what.

Comment: Notice how I never had to specify a `fusion::vector2` in the first one, so I don't really know why I have to do it for the second (Bug maybe?).
Your answer and attribute detector guided me in the right direction, so I'm voting your answer as correct, but I still don't know why I'm forced to use `fusion::vector2` in this case.

Comment: @jay1189947 Hmm. I think the most important take-away is _this_: Notice how I never even specify **any** `fusion::*` type _at all_. In my opinion, `fusion` sequences are an implementation detail, that you should only deal with when writing customization points, or perhaps when adapting structs (BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT).

Comment: Also, note that container attributes have more 'magical' properties (like `*int_ >> ';' >> *int_` can be used with a rule that exposes only a single `std::vector<int>`. But all this is getting a bit far afield. I suggest that experimenting a bit (and perhaps looking at the mechanics while doing so) is the best way to get intimate with the levels of convenience (and sometimes, surprise) that Boost Spirit has to offer.

Comment: The thing is that I'm working with more complex structures, so I can't use the default synthesized attributes and need to use the rule context to build the attributes myself through semantic actions. I have read the documentation thoroughly multiple times, so I know how compound attributes are synthesized, which is precisely why I'm so confused that my first example doesn't work (and that I still claim is a bug).
Thanks again for your time and replies!

Comment: @jay1189947 I can see your surprise. I'm not entirely convinced you should be meddling with this in your semantic actions. You'll interested in at least the following two articles: [BOOST_SPIRIT_ACTIONS_ALLOW_ATTR_COMPAT (Kaiser, Feb2011)](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Re-Spirit-general-Attribute-compatibility-and-Semantic-actions-td3306863.html) which you can just enable. Also, consider using customization points to decouple the attribute handling from your grammar definition; Search [tag:boost-spirit] for "traits" or "customization points".

Comment: This way you can achieve a grammar without semantic actions: [Semantic Actions Are Evil?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil). Finally, a link to the documentation section on customization points: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/advanced/customize.html