# Boost.Spirit grammar issue

Tags: c++, parsing, c++11, boost, boost-spirit

I am attempting to parse terminfo definitions text file. I am new to Boost.Spirit. I have started with simple grammar that only parses comment lines, empty lines and terminal definitions. As the code comment in the grammar shows, uncommenting the `[_val = _1]` for `definition` breaks compilation. Why? Can I fix it?

If I ignore the actual terminfo file, I expect the code below to parse this kind of text:

```
# comment line

first definition line
  second 
  third line

# another comment line
```

Code:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_eol.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_eoi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_object.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace termcxx
{

namespace parser
{

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
namespace px = boost::phoenix;

//using qi::double_;
using ascii::space;
//using px::ref;
using px::construct;

//using qi::eps;
//using qi::lit;
using qi::_val;
using qi::_1;
using ascii::char_;
using qi::eol;
using qi::eoi;


struct context
{
    int dummy;

    context () = default;
    context (context const &) = default;
    context (std::vector<char> a)
    { }
    context (std::vector<char> a, std::vector<char> b)
    { }
};

} }


BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    termcxx::parser::context,
    (int, dummy))


namespace termcxx
{

namespace parser
{

template <typename Iterator>
struct parser
    : qi::grammar<Iterator, context()>
{
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<char> > comment_line
    = (*space >> '#' >> *(char_ - eol) >> (eol | eoi))[_val = _1]
        ;

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<char> > empty_line
    = (*space >> (eol | eoi))[_val = _1]
        ;

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<char> > def_first_line
    = (+(char_ - eol) >> (eol | eoi))[_val = _1]
        ;

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<char> > def_subsequent_line
    = (+space >> +(char_ - eol) >> (eol | eoi))[_val = _1]
        ;

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<char> > definition
    = (def_first_line >> *def_subsequent_line)//[_val = _1] // Uncommenting the [_val = _1] breaks compilation. Why?
        ;

    qi::rule<Iterator, context()> start
    = (*(comment_line
            | empty_line
            | definition))[_val = construct<context> ()]
        ;

    parser()
        : parser::base_type(start)
    { }
};

template struct parser<std::string::iterator>;

} // namespace parser

} // namespace termcxx
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why do you insist on specifying `[_val=_1]`? It's redundant because the default attribute propagation does this. In fact it hurts, see below

Next, the attribute type of `(def_first_line >> *def_subsequent_line)` is (apparently) not compatible with `std::vector<char>`. Perhaps you can

- just use the default attribute propagation (which has enough smarts to *just keep appending*)
- use `raw[]` to get the complete matched input
- define `BOOST_SPIRIT_ACTIONS_ALLOW_ATTR_COMPAT` (I'm not sure this is well supported)

Also,

- you can replace `std::vector<char>` with `std::string` when relying on automatic attribute propagation
- you can detect the actual exposed type of a parser expression: [Detecting the parameter types in a Spirit semantic action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404189/detecting-the-parameter-types-in-a-spirit-semantic-action)

**Update**

A few more issues:

- You had mispelled the attribute types for most rules (missing `()`):

  ```
  qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> comment_line;
  qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> empty_line;
  qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> def_first_line;
  qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> def_subsequent_line;
  qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> definition;
  ```
- the `empty_line` matched at `eoi` leading to infinite loop at end of input
- the use of `char_` also accepts spaces (use `graph` instead:)

  ```
      def_first_line      = graph >> +(char_ - eol)         >> (eol|eoi);
  ```
- the use of `qi::space` also eats line-ends! Use `qi::blank` instead
- favour reability:

  ```
      empty_line          = *blank >> eol;
      comment_line        = *blank >> '#' >> *(char_ - eol) >> (eol|eoi);
      def_first_line      = graph >> +(char_ - eol)         >> (eol|eoi);
      def_subsequent_line = +blank >> +(char_ - eol)        >> (eol|eoi);

      definition          = (def_first_line >> *def_subsequent_line);

      start               = (  
                              *(comment_line | empty_line | definition)
                            ) [ _val = px::construct<context>() ]
                            ;
  ```

  This simple habit will save you hours and hours of work and your sanity when working with Spirit.
- You could simplify the includes somewhat

Here's a fixed up version **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7e191180d6137bb)** with output:

```
<start>
  <try># comment line\n\nfirs</try>
  <comment_line>
    <try># comment line\n\nfirs</try>
    <success>\nfirst definition li</success>
    <attributes>[[ , c, o, m, m, e, n, t,  , l, i, n, e]]</attributes>
  </comment_line>
  <comment_line>
    <try>\nfirst definition li</try>
    <fail/>
  </comment_line>
  <empty_line>
    <try>\nfirst definition li</try>
    <success>first definition lin</success>
    <attributes>[[]]</attributes>
  </empty_line>
  <comment_line>
    <try>first definition lin</try>
    <fail/>
  </comment_line>
  <empty_line>
    <try>first definition lin</try>
    <fail/>
  </empty_line>
  <definition>
    <try>first definition lin</try>
    <def_first_line>
      <try>first definition lin</try>
      <success>  second \n  third li</success>
      <attributes>[[f, i, r, s, t,  , d, e, f, i, n, i, t, i, o, n,  , l, i, n, e]]</attributes>
    </def_first_line>
    <def_subsequent_line>
      <try>  second \n  third li</try>
      <success>  third line\n\n# anot</success>
      <attributes>[[f, i, r, s, t,  , d, e, f, i, n, i, t, i, o, n,  , l, i, n, e,  ,  , s, e, c, o, n, d,  ]]</attributes>
    </def_subsequent_line>
    <def_subsequent_line>
      <try>  third line\n\n# anot</try>
      <success>\n# another comment l</success>
      <attributes>[[f, i, r, s, t,  , d, e, f, i, n, i, t, i, o, n,  , l, i, n, e,  ,  , s, e, c, o, n, d,  ,  ,  , t, h, i, r, d,  , l, i, n, e]]</attributes>
    </def_subsequent_line>
    <def_subsequent_line>
      <try>\n# another comment l</try>
      <fail/>
    </def_subsequent_line>
    <success>\n# another comment l</success>
    <attributes>[[f, i, r, s, t,  , d, e, f, i, n, i, t, i, o, n,  , l, i, n, e,  ,  , s, e, c, o, n, d,  ,  ,  , t, h, i, r, d,  , l, i, n, e]]</attributes>
  </definition>
  <comment_line>
    <try>\n# another comment l</try>
    <fail/>
  </comment_line>
  <empty_line>
    <try>\n# another comment l</try>
    <success># another comment li</success>
    <attributes>[[]]</attributes>
  </empty_line>
  <comment_line>
    <try># another comment li</try>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[ , a, n, o, t, h, e, r,  , c, o, m, m, e, n, t,  , l, i, n, e, !]]</attributes>
  </comment_line>
  <comment_line>
    <try></try>
    <fail/>
  </comment_line>
  <empty_line>
    <try></try>
    <fail/>
  </empty_line>
  <definition>
    <try></try>
    <def_first_line>
      <try></try>
      <fail/>
    </def_first_line>
    <fail/>
  </definition>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</start>
Success
```

Full code for reference:

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace termcxx { namespace parser {

    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
    namespace px    = boost::phoenix;

    //using qi::double_;
    using ascii::blank;
    //using px::ref;
    using px::construct;

    //using qi::eps;
    //using qi::lit;
    using qi::_val;
    using qi::_1;
    using ascii::char_;
    using ascii::graph;
    using qi::eol;
    using qi::eoi;

    struct context
    {
        int dummy;

        context () = default;
        context (context const &) = default;
        context (std::vector<char> a) { }
        context (std::vector<char> a, std::vector<char> b) { }
    };

} }

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(termcxx::parser::context, (int, dummy))

namespace termcxx { namespace parser {

    template <typename Iterator>
    struct parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, context()>
    {
        parser() : parser::base_type(start)
        { 
            empty_line          = *blank >> eol;
            comment_line        = *blank >> '#' >> *(char_ - eol) >> (eol|eoi);
            def_first_line      = graph >> +(char_ - eol)         >> (eol|eoi);
            def_subsequent_line = +blank >> +(char_ - eol)        >> (eol|eoi);

            definition          = (def_first_line >> *def_subsequent_line);

            start               = (  
                                    *(comment_line | empty_line | definition)
                                  ) [ _val = px::construct<context>() ]
                                  ;

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(def_first_line)(def_subsequent_line)(definition)(empty_line)(comment_line))
        }

      private:
        qi::rule<Iterator, context()> start;
        qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> comment_line;
        qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> empty_line;
        qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> def_first_line;
        qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> def_subsequent_line;
        qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> definition;
    };

} }

int main()
{
    using It = boost::spirit::istream_iterator;
    termcxx::parser::parser<It> g;

    It f(std::cin >> std::noskipws), l;
    termcxx::parser::context data;
    if (qi::parse(f,l,g,data))
        std::cout << "Success\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Failure\n";

    if (f != l)
        std::cout << "Remaining input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Comment: I've found a few more issues, and made it "work" (it's obviously not completed yet). See my new notes unde **Update** and the [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7e191180d6137bb)

Answer (score 2):

Let's see what exactly happens at this line:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<char> > definition
    = (def_first_line >> *def_subsequent_line)[_val = _1];
        ;
```

1. `def_first_line` is a rule. Its attribute is a
   `std::vector<char>`.
2. `def_subsequent_line` is another rule. Again
   its attribute is a `std::vector<char>`.
3. `* def_subsequent_line` is a parser obtained by applying the kleene operator `*` to the `def_subsequent_line`. Its implicit attribute is a `vector< std::vector<char> >`.
4. `(def_first_line >> *def_subsequent_line)`. This is another parser. Due to the spirit compound attribute rules, its implicit attribute is again `vector< std::vector<char> >`.

So basically, the line should read:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<std::vector<char> > > definition
    = (def_first_line >> *def_subsequent_line)[_val = _1];
        ;
```

That makes sense, doesn't it? You want to get every line separately, not all the characters together in the same vector.

Now, as side notes:

- `[_val = _1]` is not really necessary. You should initialize your rules in the grammar's constructor using the operator `%=`, which takes care of the implicit attributes.
- Assuming that you don't need to access the comments, you should write a `skipper` rule, which can automatically handle spacing and comments, and then use such rule with `phrase_parse`.
- You can use `std::string` in place of `vector<char>`, spirit is smart enough to understand that a sequence of characters is a string.
- Look [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/compound_attribute_rules.html) for the compound attribute rules.

Comment: Wow. Much Timing (I'm not too sure your crystal ball is well calibrated today, though)