# Boost spirit x3 tuple member in fusion-adapted struct

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

The following test case is a reduction of a larger, multi-file parser, hence the slightly odd order of declarations and definitions. It does not compile and my understanding is that the `std::tuple` trips it. From the docs it seems to me that the synthesized attribute there should be an std::tuple provided the correct includes are present. What am I doing wrong?

```
// -*- mode: c++; -*-

#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/std_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

#include <boost/spirit/include/support_istream_iterator.hpp>

namespace ast {

struct S {
    std::tuple< int, int > t;
    int i;
};

using boost::fusion::operator<<;

} // namespace ast

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT (ast::S, t, i)

namespace parser {

using S_type = x3::rule< struct S_class, ast::S >;
BOOST_SPIRIT_DECLARE(S_type)

struct S_class;
const S_type S = "S";

using x3::int_;
const auto S_def = ( int_ >> int_ ) >> int_;

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(S)

struct S_class { };

} // namespace parser

template< typename Iterator >
bool parse (Iterator& iter, Iterator last, ast::S& s) {
    using x3::ascii::space;

#if 1
    return x3::phrase_parse (iter, last, parser::S, space, s);
#else
    return x3::parse (iter, last, ( x3::int_ >> x3::int_ ) >> x3::int_, s);
#endif // 0
}

int main () {
    const std::string s = "1 2 3";
    auto iter = s.begin ();

    ast::S obj;
    return !parse (iter, s.end (), obj);
}
```

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: It seems that replacing the parenthesized int pair with a nonterminal that synthesizes a tuple fixes it. Or explicitly synthesizing an std::tuple via an `as<...>` directive as shown in another post. But it's still unclear why should it not work as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a nested structure. However you parse into a flat synthesized tuple that doesn't match the AST structure:

In other words `((int, int), int)` is not structurally compatible with `(int, (int, int))` or even `(int, int, int)` as your rule would parse.

The mentioned workarounds help with the attribute coercion to reflect the desired (and required) structure.

Comment: I thought that parenthesizing a sequence automatically synthesizes a `tuple`. I.e., `a >> b >> c` is a flat `tuple< int, int, int >`, but `(a >> b) >> c` is a `tuple< tuple< int, int >, int >`.  So, you're saying that is not the case, regarding of the parenthesization, in the absence of semantic actions, the synthesized attribute is a flat `tuple`.

Comment: Yes. In the old days I knew how to easily inspect the synthesized attribute type (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404189/detecting-the-parameter-types-in-a-spirit-semantic-action/9405265#9405265 or a more modernized take here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58353782/attributes-of-sequence-and-list-operator-in-boost-spirit-qi/58358181#58358181). I _think_ in X# there should be something like a`attribute_of<decltype(x3::as_parser(expression))>::type` trait but I haven't figured it out before.