try to parse a simple "\s*identifier\s+identifier\s+identifier\s*" string
I want to parse strings like these
"blub blib blab"
"\n  \n blub \t \t \n blib  \t \n  blab \n \t \n"
"  blub   blib  blab  "

and extract "blub", "blib" and "blab" into members a, b, and c of a struct (defined in the below code).
idea: i think the *qi::space and +qi::space are becomming part of my result-set and the "not correctly" filled members are the spaces that gets found
I am trying to parse some scripting language with Spirit Qi and this is my first step - after years of not using Spirit. I know that I can easily parse this with regex, but that is not my intention.
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

struct Out
{
    Out() = default;
    Out( const std::string& a_, const std::string& b_, const std::string& c_ ) : 
a( a_ ), b( b_ ), c( c_ )
    {
    }
    std::string a;
    std::string b;
    std::string c;
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT( Out, a, b, c )

int main()
{
    qi::rule<char const*, std::string()> identifier_rule = 
        qi::char_( "a-zA-Z_" ) >> *qi::char_( "a-zA-Z0-9_" );

    boost::spirit::qi::rule<char const*, Out()> abc_rule =
        *qi::space >> identifier_rule >> +qi::space >> identifier_rule >> +qi::space >> identifier_rule >> *qi::space;

    std::string test = "blub blib blab";
    //std::string test = "\n  \n blub \t \t \n blib  \t \n  blab \n \t \n";
    //std::string test = "  blub   blib  blab  ";

    Out o;
    char const* f( test.c_str() );
    char const* l( f + test.size() );
    assert( qi::parse( f, l, abc_rule, o ) );
    assert( o.a == "blub" );
    assert( o.b == "blib" );
    assert( o.c == "blab" );
    
    return 0;
}


Create an object of type std::stringstream initialized with your input string and extract (>>) into a string. Each extraction skips whitespace, so you'll get the three non-whitespace words with three extractions.

Or just do it directly: skip whitespace, copy non-whitespace, repeat until done.

You might want to print out test. The commented-out initialization does not match your example at the beginning of your question. (The string literal R"(\n)" contains no whitespace.)

There is a key piece of information that your question is missing. What are the actual values of o.a, o.b, and o.c? You told us what you expect, but what do you get? Future readers will need the exact symptom to determine if this question matches their situations.

@Peter Becker - i want to integrate that into an Spirit based script parser, manual work will not fit there

@JaMiT - damn it - was using a Raw string for \n \t tests - could not work at all - fixed that but still not the expected result

@JaMit - it think i understand the problem - my rule matches the 3 identifier AND all the space blocks around - and try to fill that into my 3 members struct - which works partially and some of the members just get the values of the space blocks

@llm " it think i understand the problem - my rule matches the 3 identifier AND all the space blocks around - and try to fill that into my 3 members struct" -- That is a reasonable conclusion to come to, if you know the actual result, something that is still missing from your question. (If "blib" is supposed to end up in o.b but ends up in o.c, a curious mind likely would wonder what happens if you keep adding fields, o.d, o.e, and so on until you don't see anything new get populated.)

I made a self-contained test-bed for all the cases:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

struct Out {
    std::string a, b, c;
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Out, a, b, c)

int main() {
    using It = std::string_view::const_iterator;
    qi::rule<It, std::string()> identifier_rule = qi::char_("a-zA-Z_") >> *qi::char_("a-zA-Z0-9_");

    qi::rule<It, Out()> abc_rule         //
        = *qi::space >> identifier_rule  //
        >> +qi::space >> identifier_rule //
        >> +qi::space >> identifier_rule //
        >> *qi::space;

    for (std::string_view test : {
             "blub blib blab",
             "\n  \n blub \t \t \n blib  \t \n  blab \n \t \n",
             "  blub   blib  blab  ",
         }) {
        It f = test.begin(), l = test.end();
        if (Out o; qi::parse(f, l, abc_rule, o))
        {
            std::cout << "Parsed:\n"
                      << "A: " << quoted(o.a) << "\n"
                      << "B: " << quoted(o.b) << "\n"
                      << "C: " << quoted(o.c) << "\n";
        } else
            std::cout << "Failed to parse " << quoted(test) << std::endl;
    }
}

The result is what I'd expect:
Parsed:
A: ""
B: "blub"
C: " "
Parsed:
A: "

 "
B: "blub"
C: "
 "
Parsed:
A: "  "
B: "blub"
C: "   "

What you probably EXPECT to happen is that qi::space are omitted. You have to tell it:
Live On Coliru
qi::rule<It, Out()> abc_rule                   //
    = qi::omit[*qi::space] >> identifier_rule  //
    >> qi::omit[+qi::space] >> identifier_rule //
    >> qi::omit[+qi::space] >> identifier_rule //
    >> qi::omit[*qi::space];

Prints
A: "blub"
B: "blib"
C: "blab"
Parsed:
A: "blub"
B: "blib"
C: "blab"
Parsed:
A: "blub"
B: "blib"
C: "blab"

WAY SIMPLER
The idiomatic approach is to use a skipper instead¹. Then becomes as simple as:
Live On Coliru
qi::rule<It, Out()> abc_rule =
    qi::skip(qi::space)[identifier_ >> identifier_ >> identifier_];

Still printing the same.

¹ See for background: Boost spirit skipper issues

thanks for the very good explanation, and the demo code - i got it!

question: i did it wrong in the first test because my spacers were not ommited - clear - but is there a verbositiy/debugging feature available in which spirit can tell me that my struct will not fit the result set?

It's subjective what "fits" a result set. Qi errs on the side of flexibility. There's rule debugging with BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b6d0a95c970d2b3. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/9404189/85371.

I think that X3 is somewhat more strict than Qi: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/097c86a20807db6b
